# Pandas: Filter datetime column using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe that has sports times as follows:

```
df:

1    05 Mar 2023 16:00
2    05 Mar 2023 16:00
3       05 Mar 2023 HT
4      05 Mar 2023 FIN
5    05 Mar 2023 90+ '
6    05 Mar 2023 18:00
7    05 Mar 2023 18:30
```

I am trying

`df= df[~df.datetime.str.contains("'|\w+$", regex=True, na=False)`]

expected df:

```
df:

1    05 Mar 2023 16:00
2    05 Mar 2023 16:00
6    05 Mar 2023 18:00
7    05 Mar 2023 18:30
```

But I get an empty dataframe.

Whats the correct way in filtering this datetime column via regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `\w+$` matches any *alphanumeric* characters immediately before the end of the string, which all rows other than the one ending in `'` match, since they either end with letters or digits. You should use `[A-Za-z]` instead. Note that you don't need `+` as an entry that ends with multiple letters also ends with 1 letter:

```py
df = df[~df.datetime.str.contains("'|[A-Za-z]$", regex=True, na=False)]
```

Output:

```
1    05 Mar 2023 16:00
2    05 Mar 2023 16:00
6    05 Mar 2023 18:00
7    05 Mar 2023 18:30
```

Comment: While the solution answers the question raised, why does `\w+$` match any alphanumeric character before the end of the string? Since `$` asserts position at the end of a line, doesn't the logic still apply?

Comment: @PyNoob, sorry, I should have said *immediately* before the end of string. For your data, that match is `00`, `00`, `HT`, `FIN`', (no match), `00` and `30`